# Covariance between fluctuating number of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, covariance

Suppose $X_i$, i=1...N, are not-independent random variables identically distributed. Then, take $N_1$ to be a random variable in the interval $[0,N]$. I now define the "composite" random variables
$$
Y(N_1) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_1} X_i \qquad Z(N-N_1) = \sum_{i=N_1+1}^{N} X_i \;,
$$
and I want to calculate
$$
\text{Cov}[Y(N_1),Z(N-N_1)] = ...
$$

I'm interested in obtaining an expression involving moments of the distributions for $X$ and $N$.

My attempt was to say
$$
\text{Cov}[Y(N_1),Z(N-N_1)] = \mathbb{E}[ \sum_{i=1}^{N_1}\sum_{j=N_1+1}^{N} \text{Cov}[X_i,X_j] ] \\
= \mathbb{E}[ N_1(N-N_1) \text{Cov}[X_i,X_j] ] \\
= (N\langle N_1\rangle-\langle N_1^2\rangle) \text{Cov}[X_i,X_j] 
$$

which is WRONG!

Where is the mistake?

Comment: When you take the covariance you have to condition on the value of $N_1$. You can then use the tower property of expectations to work out the actual covariance, all things considered.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst thank you for the comment, but isn't this what I'm already doing?